# Filter row from an array if value is between two cells

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a price table like the example below:

[image: Price Table]

I need to filter the table so depending on what i have on "m2 total" and "material" it returns the correct price. "m2 total" will be often values between two of the values on column A but sometimes it could be a number under 250 or above 2500.

In case G1 it's equal to any of the values on column A, I need it to filter the row with that value and the column with the correct material.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: How do you want to handle values above 2500 and below 250?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, if below 250, it returns the correct price on first row for asigned material and if it's above 2500 it returns correct price on last row.

Comment: And if it's between two quantities in column A do you take the higher price, so in your example of 750 would it be 3.54 euros?

Comment: That's it, it must take the higher price if the quantity of m2 does not reach the next value on column A. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(
  B2:D6, 
  IFERROR(MATCH(G1, A2:A6, 1), 1), 
  MATCH(G2, B1:D1, 0))
```

`IFERROR(MATCH(G1, A2:A6, 1), 1)` Looks through the prices ascendingly (Uses the matching unit count or next smaller one), if it is under 250 it will fall back to the first row.